# How many strings is too many for an android app

Tags: android, string, resources

I am creating a language learning app and  I have a section in the app that will be dependent on fairly large amounts of text. about 800 words per activity, spread out over different text views. I am planning to store the  paragraphs / sentences in the strings resource. which will more o less equate to 100 strings per activty and about 10 activties.

In total the  R.jar file will have between 1000 -1500 seperate string id's.Is this a lot or too much for an app. Will this make my app really slow or is it normal practice for a text based app?

I know that I could store the data in sqlite database but prepoulating the database then filtering results and placing each string into its corresponding view programatically would be a real pain in the neck and I think would be even slower. and I would prefer to declare the string in the xml layout straight from the resource.

Comment: If you need 1000 to 1500 string you need them. Nothing to do about that.

Comment: R.java has an integer field for each string. If you have 1500 strings in your strings.xml, that comes out to 6000 bytes (1500 * 4) of storage for your string IDs, which is pretty minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Android creates **static references** for all strings you place in Resources and application will load all instances in memory when app is launched.
Its unnecessary object creation.
You should go for creating a db for all words and use when they are required.

Comment: Well, if he is going to use all those strings at the same time (even if only 100 per activity), then it doesn't really make a difference.